# Setup SSL for PDO-MySQL on Fedora

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo, fedora

I want to setup SSL for MySQL on Fedora. I am using PDO as MySQL-connector in PHP. But it is not working.

The PHP-version (php -v) is:

> PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2015 13:46:39)

When I check `php -m` I get a long list, including openssl, PDO, pdo_mysql, mysql.

In `/etc/my.cnf` I added the "ssl" and the three certificates (CA-root, private-key, certificate). I restarted MySQL and Apache.

The pdo-connector is this:

```
function getDBConn() {
    return new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=forum',
        user,
        pass,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => path_to_same_as_in_my.cnf.key,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => path_to_same_as_in_my.cnf.crt,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => path_to_same_as_in_my.cnf.crt
        )

}
```

But on the pages that connect to the database I get the following errors:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 78
Warning: PDO::__construct(): cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 78
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] (trying to connect via unix:///var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock) in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 78
FATAL ERROR: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQL:STATE[HY000][2002]' in /var/www/html/functions.php:78 Stack trace .....
```

Anyone who has a solution for this?

Comment: [Possible solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=this+stream+does+not+support+SSL%2Fcrypto). Btw, did you copy+paste the error exactly? I notice the word "support" is misspelled - if that is correct then maybe it's a different message.

Comment: I didn't copy it. I'm using Fedora in VirtualBox, so copy pasting doesn't work.

Comment: Righto. As an aside, copy+pasting in VirtualBox _should_ work just fine. I'm using Ubuntu/VirtualBox and it's fine there. Is your browser environment that you're using for Stack Overflow outside of VirtualBox? Check to see if 'Devices > Shared Clipboard' is set to 'Bidirectional'.

Comment: Nope. Still not working. But ontopic: do you know anything else? The url you provided didn't have a solution for me. Or should I just go with MySQLi?

Comment: I've no experience with MySQL and SSL, unfortunately. Do have a good look through those search results though - that URL isn't just one solution, it's _hundreds_ of possible solutions. I imagine it is possible that one of them fits your situation `:-)`

Comment: (Personally I would not switch from one engine to another on this basis, since it is quite a large change in itself. But if you have not already written the application and are happy to use a different driver, perhaps it is worth a go?)

Comment: Have you tried running the smallest possible test-case from the console? I wonder if it is a permissions problem on those keys - maybe Apache cannot see them?

Comment: Well, it's a school assignment to build a small forum that's protected against everything. I have setup https and now I want ssl for mysql. I already tried a mysqli-function, but I get a "Bad handshake" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this for PDO MySQL using SSL

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
    )
);
$statement = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

Another biggest reason you're getting the error is because you might not have `openssl` installed.

Comment: I can confirm that I have installed openssl (sudo yum install openssl). The code you give is what I have. (except that I use the prepare-statements)

Comment: After all this worked. I had some issues with the certificates. (exported the wrong one from xca))